# Match values in data frame with values in another data frame and replace former with a corresponding pattern from the other data frame

Tags: r, replace, pattern-matching, dataframe

Complicated title but here is a simple example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
d <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
                v2 = c("A","E","C","B","B","C","A","E"))

m <- data.frame(v3 = c("D","E","A","C","D","B"), 
                v4 = c("d","e","a","c","d","b"))
```

Values in `d$v2` should be replaced by values in `m$v4` by matching the values from `d$v2` in `m$v3`

The resulting data frame `d` should look like:

```
v1    v4
1      a
2      e
3      c
4      b
5      b
6      c
7      a
8      e
```

I tried different stuff and the closest I came was: `d$v2 <- m$v4[which(m$v3 %in% d$v2)]`

I try to avoid any for-loops again! Must be possible :-) somehow... ;)

Answer (score 20):

You could try:

```
merge(d,m, by.x="v2", by.y="v3")
  v2 v1 v4
1  A  1  a
2  A  7  a
3  B  4  b
4  B  5  b
5  C  3  c
6  C  6  c
7  E  2  e
8  E  8  e
```

### Edit

Here is another approach, to preserve the order:

```
data.frame(v1=d$v1, v4=m[match(d$v2, m$v3), 2])
  v1 v4
1  1  a
2  2  e
3  3  c
4  4  b
5  5  b
6  6  c
7  7  a
8  8  e
```

Comment: I tried merge but it changes the order and I want to keep the order of data frame d. Could of course add a column "order" to d first and after applying merge resort on that column but then I need to drop it again. It's a bit over the top I guess, isn't it?

Comment: yeah match does the job! fantastic. the rest is easy to understand. there are so many of these things such as `match` `which` `%in%` `is.element` etc and also so many combinations that it's sometimes just difficult to find the right one.. umm :)

Comment: The second solution by johannes worked, not quite what I wanted still better than merge.

Answer (score 11):

You could use a standard left join.

Loading the data:

```
d <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), v2 = c("A","E","C","B","B","C","A","E"), stringsAsFactors=F)
m <- data.frame(v3 = c("D","E","A","C","D","B"), v4 = c("d","e","a","c","d","b"), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Changing column name, such that I can join by column "v2"

```
colnames(m) <- c("v2", "v4")
```

Left joining and maintaining the order of data.frame d

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(d, m)
```

Output:

```
  v1 v2 v4
1  1  A  a
2  2  E  e
3  3  C  c
4  4  B  b
5  5  B  b
6  6  C  c
7  7  A  a
8  8  E  e
```

Answer (score 11):

This will give you the desired output:

```
d$v2 <- m$v4[match(d$v2, m$v3)]
```

match function returns the position from m matrix's v3 column for the values in `d$v2` being matched. Once you have obtained the indices (from using `match()`), access elements from `m$v4` using those indices to replace the elements in d matrix, column v2.